# Alternative to unicode for a subscript lowercase g

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I cannot add characters to a chart legend in subscript or superscript through standard fonts. Unicode however works. The problem is I need a lowercase g in subscript, and Unicode does not support this. Are there any alternative fonts or methods that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Create a borderless textbox which contains your label text.

It won't be linked to your column heading, but you will be able to use subscript (and superscript).

Comment: Can I link this to the legend key, or do I have to do something wonky like leave the legend up and place a textbox over the text?

Comment: This is a workaround.  You'd have to put a textbox over the text.  If you make the background of the textbox white, it'll hide whatever is below.